# High voltage (500V) measurement by scaling down voltage

Tags: high-voltage, voltage-measurement

We are looking to develop a precharge circuit in which we require to measure voltage  for which we are scaling 0-500V to 0-5/10V. In this paricular component we get an output which can be given to an ADC. There was a particular component which I found V500-ISO which scaled voltage from 0-500V to 0-5V but the issue with the component was it wasn"t available and was very expensive. So I looked for similar components one of them being ISO224 by texas instruments. In a particular application the output of ISO224 was fed into a precision amplifier. So the couple of questions which rose were is the voltage the same as input voltage ie 0-12V which is the voltage across the R2 resistor in the above diagram or does it correspond to the voltage on the output side which can be -0.3 to 6.8V and the other question is as all the parameters are given for AC voltage can this component be used for DC application. The details regarding all the specifications are listed in the pitcures and datasheets attached below.[image]
[image] [image]

Comment: Does it need to be an isolation amplifier?

Comment: yes preferably as it involves both high voltage and low voltage

Comment: I don't see any specs on precision, accuracy, long term drift, repeatability between instrumentation (if needed), etc. And can a minimum bandwidth also be taken as DC to 600 Hz and not one Hz more? Or? Depending on what you say, a number of isolated (and not expensive) ideas come to mind.

Comment: Can you suggest some as it could be of great help. I tried to find basic optocouplers but couldn't find any of them rated for 500V

Comment: For one, you could easily use a self-triggered relaxation oscillator (whose frequency would depend directly upon the voltage) to provide opto-isolated pulses (say, via 6N137 as an example.) These could either be fed to a cheap MCU that converts the pulse rate to some voltage reading you like or else just directly fed to a frequency to voltage converter for an ADC, if that's what you want. You can avoid boutique parts, hard to find ones, etc. But a lot depends on what you really need to do and I'm just tossing mud at the wall to see if any of it sticks.

Comment: There are also charge collection methods (as the voltage will place small surface charges, as it must do, on the conductor.) This is basically a pith-ball concept, but made into electronic instrument instead of a toy. And still more ideas. I'm sure others know things I don't know to suggest, as well. Don't limit your imagination!

Comment: I actually don't have to deal with an AC signal so frequency is not a factor. I wanted to clarify if the above mentioned component could also be used for a DC application. But thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, in fact it is EASIER if it is DC. (I assumed if it were AC you'd just use a transformer or other non-contact inductive method.)

Comment: @mohitmahajan Just use a big R value (lots of R's in series would be better, for many reasons) with a small capacitor. This will limit any possibility of dangerous stored charge on the cap, too. The voltage rises on the cap and a self-triggering SCR is used to discharge the cap when the voltage reaches a "trigger voltage" you set. The discharge current is sent through an LED (the opto diode) which uses light to cross your isolation barrier and is received as a "pulse event" on the other side of the isolation. This should easily work from 50 V to 750 V.

Comment: @mohitmahajan Just look at it as a ramp generator, if that helps.Set the trigger voltage "low" (say 2.5 V?) This means that the resistor will, in effect, represent a current source whose value is (almost) directly dependent upon the applied voltage. (Higher voltages produce almost unvarying current, while lower voltages will present slightly more varying current because of the trigger level being "non-zero.") This current source feeds a capacitor, which ramps up linearly. When it reaches the trigger point, the SCR fires and discharges it through the LED diode, and the cycle repeats.

Comment: @mohitmahajan By your choice of the series-R and the capacitance, you can decide what loading on your voltage source is acceptable and also set the range of frequency you will have to process. So you have a lot of control and options when choosing the R and C. Since the pulsing circuitry can be self-powered and completely sealed up in ceramics from [Cotronics](https://www.cotronics.com/vo/cotr/) (for example), you can make this very safe and easy to apply.

Comment: But I want to do actually is in an Electric vehicle motor controller capacitor is charged through a resistor this is called pre charge. So when the capacitor charges to 95% of the battery voltage i need a signal. So for this reason i am scaling high voltage to a lower voltage so that it can be fed into a mcu.

Comment: @mohitmahajan Just feed the pulses to the MCU, then. Let it do the rest. Given this "95%" figure, I'm now almost certain a relaxation oscillator will work fine for you.

Comment: @mohitmahajan You'd need to do your own design, but you could [look here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/319916/38098) for something like what I'm suggesting to you. That one isn't very different from what would be needed for 750 V. Not at all expensive or difficult. I've used something similar for up to 20 kV, in fact. No problems.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @mohitmahajan If it's helpful, feel free to +1 that answer. What's being done there is a little bit behavioral. Keep in mind that while I show just two resistors going to HV, you cannot count on more than 200 V or so between small resistor bodies and you should include several anyway because of the possibility of a fail-short of any one of them (or other kind of accidental short.)

Comment: @mohitmahajan I'd also recommend potting the entire HV circuit to avoid multiple exposed points of HV. Best would be to use HV ceramic potting compound (Resbond 919 or 920) and either their 902 machinable alumina silicate (out of which you'd mill an enclosure box) or their rigid ceramic boards, or both. The result will only have 5 wires: isolated HV (+) and (-) and then Vcc, Gnd, and MCU I/O pin. Place the HV pins as far from each other and other pins as possible, of course.

Comment: @mohitmahajan The [Cotronics](https://www.cotronics.com/vo/cotr/) website may not look like much, but their products have been a godsend when I've needed something specialized for high voltage or high temperature, as a hobbyist anyway. Their ceramic hardstock has \$10^{14}\:\Omega-\text{cm}\$ bulk resistivity and can withstand \$500\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{mil}}\$ and doesn't shrink, doesn't absorb moisture, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a DC measurement would look like:

[image: iso1]

And here is the AC measurement. In both cases, 2.5V can be made from 500V with a 5V secondary power supply. The primary power supply is 12V.[image: iso2]

Comment: Thanks a lot could you help me with the software in which you have simulated this? And in the first case could i scale a 500VDC down to 10VDC?

Comment: This is the [Tina-TI](https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI) program. There is the sample circuit as well at the component (ISO224). The input must be reduced below 10V because the secondary supply voltage can only be 5V. Thus, at 500V, the input voltage is 7.5V.

Comment: The secondary supply voltage can be 6.5V and the output can be recorded till 15V, so the voltage can be increased in my view. I will try it on the Tina-TI software.

Comment: Do not plan continuous operation at [maximum](https://imgur.com/a/uUpSu39) values. It can only tolerate them for a short time. On the secondary side you can use an extra amplifier if necessary.

Comment: Where do I find the component and sample circuit in the Tina-TI software

Comment: In this section: Design and [Development](https://www.ti.com/product/ISO224?qgpn=iso224).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a safe earth ground, this is trivial using 50% derated string of 250V resistors dissipating <25% rated power with 1M total scaled down to 10k then coated with 2mm of silicone RTV to prevent contamination (dust&RH) induced creapage .

If you expect transients, add a Zener or Clamp diodes and series 10k R to CMOS input.